# Moving mouse in direction and rate

Tags: c#, vector, mouse, emulation, joystick

I'm trying to create a simple mouse emulator controlled by a joystick's right thumbstick.  I was trying to have the mouse move in the direction the stick pointed with a smooth gradient of pressure values dictating speed, but I've hit a number of snags when trying to do so.

The first is how to accurately translate the angle into accurate X and Y values.  I can't find a way to implement the angle correctly.  The way I have it, the diagonals are likely to move considerably faster than the cardinals.
I was thinking I need something like Math.Cos(angle) for the X values, and Math.Sin(angle) for the Y values to increment the mouse, but I can't think of a way to set it up.

The second, is smooth movement of the mouse, and this is probably the more important of the two.  Since the SetPosition() function only works with integers, the rate at which pixels move over time seems very limited.  The code I have is very basic, and only registers whole number values of 1-10.  That not only creates small 'jumps' in acceleration, but limits diagonal movement as well.
The goal would to have something like 10 pixels-per-second, with the program running at 100hz, and each cycle outputting 0.1 pixel movement.

I'd imagine I might be able to keep track of the pixel 'decimals' for the X and Y values and add them to the axes when they build to whole numbers, but I'd imagine there's a more efficient way to do so and still not anger the SetPosition() function.

I feel like Vector2 objects should get this done, but I don't know how the angle would fit in.

Sample code:

```
        //Poll Gamepad and Mouse.  Update all variables.
    public void updateData(){

        padOne = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One, GamePadDeadZone.None);
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        currentStickRX = padOne.ThumbSticks.Right.X;
        currentStickRY = padOne.ThumbSticks.Right.Y;
        currentMouseX = mouse.X;
        currentMouseY = mouse.Y;
        angle = Math.Atan2(currentStickRY, currentStickRX);

        vectorX = (int)( currentStickRX*10 );
        vectorY = (int)( -currentStickRY*10 );
        mouseMoveVector.X = vectorX;
        mouseMoveVector.Y = vectorY;


        magnitude = Math.Sqrt(  Math.Pow( (currentStickRX - 0), 2 ) + Math.Pow( (currentStickRY - 0), 2 )  );
        if (magnitude > 1){
            magnitude = 1;
        }

        //Get values not in deadzone range and re-scale them from 0-1
        if(magnitude >= deadZone){
            activeRange = (magnitude - deadZone)/(1 - deadZone);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();  //Test Code
    }

    //Move mouse in in direction at specific rate.
    public void moveMouse(){
        if (magnitude > deadZone){
            Mouse.SetPosition( (currentMouseX + vectorX), (currentMouseY + vectorY));
        }


        previousStickRX = currentStickRX;
        previousStickRY = currentStickRY;
        previousActiveRange = activeRange;
    }
```

Note:  I'm using all the xna frameworks.

Anyway,  apologies if I'm explaining these things incorrectly.  I haven't been able to find a good resource for this, and the vector examples I searched only move in integer increments and from point A to B.

Any help with any part of this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but from my point of view, you should normalize the pad axis after reading them, that way diagonals would move the same speed as cardinals. And for the second part, I would keep track of the mouse in floating variables, such as a Vector2 and do the cast (maybe rounding better) when setting the mouse position.

```
public void Start()
{
   mousePosV2 = Mouse.GetState().Position.ToVector2();
}

public void Update(float dt)
{
   Vector2 stickMovement = padOne.ThumbSticks.Right;
   stickMovement.Normalize();
   mousePosV2 += stickMovement*dt*desiredMouseSpeed; 

   /// clamp here values of mousePosV2 according to Screen Size
   /// ...

   Point roundedPos = new Point(Math.Round(mousePosV2.X), Math.Round(mousePosV2.Y));
   Mouse.SetPosition(roundedPos.X, roundedPos.Y);
}
```

Comment: Alright, cool.  The code
"mousePosV2 += stickMovement*dt*desiredMouseSpeed; "
was the general structure I was hoping to get, and normalizing the stick vector was a great idea.

Thanks a ton for your help.